# Transforming Parser[Any] to a Stricter Type

Tags: scala, parsing

Programming in Scala's Chapter 33 explains [Combinator Parsing](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html):

It provides this example:

```
  import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

  class Arith extends JavaTokenParsers {   
    def expr: Parser[Any] = term~rep("+"~term | "-"~term)
    def term: Parser[Any] = factor~rep("*"~factor | "/"~factor)
    def factor: Parser[Any] = floatingPointNumber | "("~expr~")"
  }
```

How can I map `expr` to a narrower type than `Parser[Any]`? In other words,

I'd like to take `def expr: Parser[Any]` and map that via `^^` into a stricter type.

**Note** - I asked this question in Scala Google Groups - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-user, but haven't received a complete answer that helped me out.

Comment: You normally use a parser to map a `String` to an instance of a data structure. What is your data structure here? Then `Any` could be replaced by types of this structure.

Comment: Yes, can't you simply replace Any with another type and make that you return something of that type...?

Comment: @Kigyo, I was hoping for that AST in the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, you can narrow down the type to anything you like. You just have to specify it after the `^^`.

Here is a complete example with a data structure from your given code.

```
object Arith extends JavaTokenParsers {

  trait Expression //The data structure
  case class FNumber(value: Float) extends Expression
  case class Plus(e1: Expression, e2: Expression) extends Expression
  case class Minus(e1: Expression, e2: Expression) extends Expression
  case class Mult(e1: Expression, e2: Expression) extends Expression
  case class Div(e1: Expression, e2: Expression) extends Expression

  def expr: Parser[Expression] = term ~ rep("+" ~ term | "-" ~ term) ^^ {
    case term ~ rest => rest.foldLeft(term)((result, elem) => elem match {
      case "+" ~ e => Plus(result, e)
      case "-" ~ e => Minus(result, e)
    })
  }

  def term: Parser[Expression] = factor ~ rep("*" ~ factor | "/" ~ factor) ^^ {
    case factor ~ rest => rest.foldLeft(factor)((result, elem) => elem match {
      case "*" ~ e => Mult(result, e)
      case "/" ~ e => Div(result, e)
    })
  }

  def factor: Parser[Expression] = floatingPointNumber ^^ (f => FNumber(f.toFloat)) | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"

  def parseInput(input: String): Expression = parse(expr, input) match {
    case Success(ex, _) => ex
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException //or change the result to Try[Expression]
  }
}
```

Now we can start to parse something.

```
Arith.parseInput("(1.3 + 2.0) * 2")
//yields: Mult(Plus(FNumber(1.3),FNumber(2.0)),FNumber(2.0))
```

Of course you can also have a `Parser[String]` or a `Parser[Float]`, where you directly transform or evaluate the input String. It is as I said up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that this post would enhance the quality of the Scala Docs on this particular example.